# How to initialize the driver to avoid NullPointerException error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I am having an issue with this class where I am receiving a null pointer exception. I inserted `System.out.println("driver=" + driver);`  to see what is outputted and it states the `driver=null` for each dataset which makes me think there is a problem with the initialization when I hit the method under @Test. How can I resolve this initialization of the driver to get my tests to pass in testNG?

Below is the code:

```
package com.testng.practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class LoginTest {

        WebDriver driver = null;

        @BeforeTest
        public void invokeApplication() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "xxx\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        }   

        @Test (dataProvider = "getData")
        public void loginFaceBook(String email, String password) {

            System.out.println("driver=" + driver); 

            WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
            WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));

            emailField.sendKeys(email);
            passwordField.sendKeys(password);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] getData(){

            //declared object of 4 rows and 2 columns

            Object[][] dataSet = new Object[4][2];

            dataSet[0][0] = "TimSmith@gmail.com";
            dataSet[0][1] = "Smith123";

            dataSet[1][0] = "JaneMcCormack@gmail.com";
            dataSet[1][1] = "McCormack123";

            dataSet[2][0] = "AnjaliPrakash@gmail.com";
            dataSet[2][1] = "Prakash123";

            dataSet[3][0] = "JamesBean@gmail.com";
            dataSet[3][1] = "Bean123";

            return dataSet;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` to `this.driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: That fixed it thank you. Can I ask you and feel free to place it in answer so I can mark it as best answer and up vote it but how come this.driver... works compared to WebDriver?

Comment: You can use [qaf](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf) which is testng implementation for web mobile and webservice test automation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition of the `driver` variable is valid within the `invokeApplication()` method and leaves the class attribute `driver` uninitialized

`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

to initialize the class attribute use:

`this.driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem should be in the @BeforeTest annotation if you are running the class it self by running as TestNG.
BeforeTest annotation is working before the tag  in the xml runner file.
Here is the definition of BeforeTest from TestNG documentation.
@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run. 
If you want to run before @Test you need to use @BeforeMethod.

Please pay attentionto the differences between all the annotation.
You can find differences [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations).

Answer (score -1):

you declare WebDriver driver=null; Globally.
Then No Need To Declare once in Method invokeApplication();
write only
 WebDriver driver = null;

```
    @BeforeTest
    public void invokeApplication() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "xxx\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```